# Hi, I would like help with the product or the box topology please.

Tags: general-topology

Space includes itself as a subset, so does that mean spaces in a product count each other toward the requirement that *all but finitely many* of the subsets in each component aren't equal to the component? Otherwise I don't see how an infinite product of real number lines can fail to have the product topology or how a box topology is finer. Please help me thank you very much and I will be back to give reputation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing the finite product of spaces they will be the same topology. But suppose we want $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the space of sequences. Well in the product topology where we can only use a finite number of open sets other than $\mathbb{R}$ itself $\prod (0,1)$ will not be an open set there, but it will be the box topology because there we can consider an open set other than the whole space in every coordinate function. This is why the box topology will be finer because in the box topology we can always have a a finite product of open sets other than $\mathbb{R}$ with the rest $\mathbb{R}$, say $...\times U \times V \times \mathbb{R} ... $ where the rest are $\mathbb{R}$, will be open in the two topologies, but $\prod (0,1)$ will not be open in the product topology becacuse it would have to contain a base element but then in an infinite number of coordinates we would have an $\mathbb{R}$ and well we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is not contained in $(0,1)$.

Im not sure how familiar you are with algebra but its the same as the product and the sum , they are the same in the finite case, but if are doing them an infinite number of times, in the direct sum only a finite number of entraces will not be trivial , while in the product we can have all the entris non-trivial.

When i first though about this, if i had to define a topology on a product the box topology would be the way to go for me, you just take the product of all open sets in all topologies seems good, but as you will se later this topology is enourmous and is not really something we want to work with for function spaces.Also another thing that we would want to be true, is that when we have a product of sets a function will be continuous iff it is continuous in each of its coordinates, well this will fail to be true in box topology, because this topology is so big, but it will be true in the product topology.

Comment: The box topology is "never" compact, "never" connected etc. Much worse behaved than the usual product topology. It seems weirder at first, but is in fact more natural.